# How to position a pseudo selector using position property in CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to position a pseudo selector (first-letter) left from the div

I tried giving the parent DIV position Relative and the pseduo selector ( div::first-letter ) postion absolute and it didnt work

```html
  font-family: "Franklin Gothic Medium", "Arial Narrow", Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 55px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #d4d4d4;
  color: black;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}

div::first-letter {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 60px;
  color: white;
  left: 90px;
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`position` is not one of the [properties usable with `::first-letter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter#allowable_properties). Some of the available properties could be used to push text around, such as `padding` and `line-height`.